# How do you hint different options for a function's object parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm implementing a library in TypeScript and some functions are as follows:

`constructor(type: TypeEnum, params: {[id:string]: any})`

The thing is, whenever I use the library using js, I would like my IDE to display every single valid `id` of `params`. I have seen some libraries already do this, how do I achieve it?

Comment: What are your constraints?

Comment: What _is_ every single valid id of params? As currently typed, it's literally any possible string; how do you expect an IDE to show all of those?

Comment: Simplified, I want to be able to see the options of id when typing the function. So when I type in my ide `let obj = new MyClass( TypeEnum.YELLOW, {})` I can see the different ids.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, that is my question. Lets say the valid id of params are 'option1' and 'option2', for example

Comment: So give a more specific type than `{[id: string]: any}`. Read the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set them explicitly as properties:

```
constructor(type: TypeEnum, params: { option1?: any, option2?: any })
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it like this `{ option1?: any, option2?: any }` or like this `{ 'option1'?: any, 'option2'?: any }`. Why?

Comment: @MiguelLuna shouldn't make a difference with or without quotes